# Optimal solution in SVM algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, svm

I have gone through SVM algorithm in "`Insight into Data Mining Theory and Practice`".

```
Page 253 Example 10.1
```

In that ,the algorithm stops with finding `Wtranspose X -gama`
and found there are `3 misclassifications`.

And tells the `accuracy` of the
classifier in the training set is `70%`. So is that the `final optimum solution` or is there
any `iteration` done in svm.
If so pls tell me from where to start iteration and from which data we should start iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVM is trained in the iterative fashion in order to find the **global optimum**. So it is not getting stuck in some suboptimal solutions like neural networks etc. but is still trained in the iterative way, as closed form solutions do not exist for such problems. One has to note, that this optimum is defined in terms of minimizing the SVM optimization term, containing weighted sum of margin size and misclassification count, which is far from actually optimizing the accuracy (or any other evaluation metric) although you can artificially train a model, which will have 100% accuracy on the training set by using RBF kernel, and very big C and gamma which will force your SVM to overfit your data (this will degenerate to trivial model, which simply memorizes training set, and will be useless, but you will see a "100%" score). So - yes - result of the training is the "final form" of your model and the accuracy below 100% is **expected**.

The second question - where "to start the iteration" does not make sense. In a classical approach, the problem is transformed into its dual interpretation where the SMO algorithm is ran in order to find the optimum of the convex function on the linearly bounded subspace of Lagrange multiplayers. And iterations goes through points violating KKT optimality conditions, so these are point to "start with".

Comment: can you give me an example link for doing svm.i am stuck with w trans x -gama.i dnt know to move further.I stuffed through internet..i was not able to find a gud tutorial

Comment: I do not undestand what you mean by "doing svm".SVM is just a model, and you have dozens of libraries implementing it, when all you need to do is set some parameters (C and gamma for RBF kernel) and give a training set. That's all - you do not analyze what is going inside. One of very easy to follow libraries in python `sklearn` (sklearn.org) with nice tutorials. If you want to understand the math behind SVMs - you could give Haykin's Neural Networks book a try

Comment: I want to know the maths behind it

Comment: www.croce.ggf.br/dados/K%20mean%20Clustering1.pdf was a good tutorial to workout k-means. I am in search of similar tutorial related to SVM

Comment: K-means is like a childs toy in comparision to SVM. There is much, much more complex math behind it, so in order to understand it you will have to face more complex approach. If you seek for something light, you can try to follow the slides presentation http://webdoc.nyumc.org/nyumc/files/chibi/user-content/Final.pdf but I will still suggest some good book read, as SVM requires much optimization theory for good understanding. Some list of tutorials: http://www.kernel-machines.org/tutorials